# Avoid the yellow message at the top of the gnome-terminal window that states "The child process exited normally with status 0."

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a gnome-terminal profile created with "When the command exists: Hold the terminal open" set. How can I avoid the yellow message at the top of the gnome-terminal window that states "The child process exited normally with status 0."?

Below are the contents of the desktop entry I have pinned to the Unity launcher. File name: twitterText.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=vinagre
Name=Text Twitter Timeline
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Microblog --hide-menubar --command="/usr/bin/python /home/htplainf/twitterTimeline.py"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, don't let the program you are running terminate!
That yellow line indicates that the command you called within gnome-terminal finished sucessfully. You can even hit "relaunch" to start the program (in this case, your command line twitter) again.

I would do the following: Since you are most likely interested in a continuous update of the twitter messages, run your program within the `watch` command. This way, you can even define the interval "twitterTimeline.py" is run again!

Change your twitterText.desktop into the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=vinagre
Name=Text Twitter Timeline
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Microblog --hide-menubar --command="watch -t -n 60 '/usr/bin/python /home/htplainf/twitterTimeline.py'"
```

Have a look at the Exec command in the last line:

```
watch -t -n 60 '/usr/bin/python /home/htplainf/twitterTimeline.py'
```

`-n 60` means that your python script is executed every 60 seconds. You can easily set a different interval. Also, have a look at `man watch` to discover its compete functionality!

By using watch, your command never stops, so you will not see the yellow message bar on top of gnome-terminal. And your tweets are updated!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I added `raw_input()` to the end of my Python script and removed "Hold the terminal open" from the gnome-terminal profile. This works perfect for my use case. I don't want to refresh the content as I have a twitter feed displayed by conky. I only open this terminal twitter feed when I've spotted something interesting with a link. I can click on the link from here. When I'm done, I press Enter and the terminal goes away. Perfect!

Comment: I agree :-) That also prevents the process from stopping and closes the terminal. Nice!

Answer (score -1):

Your terminal setting may have,

> Edit > Profile Preferences > Title and Command > When command exits:
>   Hold the terminal open

set,

> When command exits:Exit the terminal