# How can I move the Gnome Terminal message "the child process exited ..."?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I just installed an IDE extension that runs the current program in a terminal, and I have Gnome Terminal set to stay open when the command exits, but when that happens, the first two lines are covered up by the message "The child process exited normally with status 0". How could I move it?

I believe this is possible by editing a Gnome stylesheet, but I'm not sure where to start.

### Example

Here's a simple Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

x = input('Enter something: ')
print('You entered:', x)
```

I run it and type something:

[image: screenshot showing "Enter something: foobar"]

*(My system is in French.)*

Then as soon as I press Enter, the script exits and the message pops up, blocking the output:

[image: screenshot showing output blocked by message]

I'd rather have the message somewhere else, like at the bottom for example. Here's a mockup:

[image: mockup showing output unblocked by putting the message at the bottom]

You can reproduce the issue by saving the script as `tmp.py` then running `gnome-terminal -- python3 tmp.py`. And make sure you have Gnome Terminal set up correctly: go to **Edit** → **Preferences** → **Command** → **When the command exits** and select *Hold the terminal open*.

### Possible workarounds

- Make the program hold the terminal open, e.g. `input('Press Enter to finish...')`. -- I'd rather not have to put that on everything I write.

  ---

  **Update**: I ended up using something like this. I wrote a script as sort of a shim for my IDE code-runner extension to run, and the shim runs the program and puts a prompt at the end, sort of like this:

  ```bash
  "${launcher[@]}" "$program" "$@"
  read -rsp "[Exit status $?. Press Enter to finish.]"; echo
  ```

  (Where, for the example above, `launcher=(/usr/bin/env python3)` and `program=tmp.py`, which are passed in by the code-runner.)
- Use an integrated IDE terminal. -- I haven't found a good one yet, and I prefer using the native terminal for most things.
- Relaunch the program after it exits. -- If it has any side-effects, that might be bad, for example if it reads and writes any files.

### Related

- [Avoid the yellow message at the top of the gnome-terminal window that states "The child process exited normally with status 0."](https://askubuntu.com/q/178334/301745)

Comment: By following your steps I can not reproduce this on `GNOME Terminal 3.40.3`. I.e. I execute your script inside Gnome Terminal, then I enter `foobar` into the prompt, and press enter, I see no pop ups from the terminal. I presume it may have been fixed in more recent versions of Gnome Terminal.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for the lead! I'm using GNOME Terminal 3.28.2. But where do you see the exit code come up? Or is it missing?

Comment: I don't see exit code anywhere. Here's a screenshot of what I see: https://i.imgur.com/LPR4AYa.png

Comment: @Hi-Angel Oh, you're launching it from a shell! You'll need to use `exec ./test.py` to reproduce the issue. The extension I'm using does the equivalent of `gnome-terminal -- ./test.py`, which launches a new terminal.

Comment: When I use `exec test.py`, Gnome Terminal simply quits right after I type into the prompt "foobar". So, well, still no pop up, although I guess that's not what you wanted ☺ I think you may have better luck getting correct answers if you add to your post the exact steps to reproduce, preferably as minimal as possible.

Comment: @Hi-Angel You need to have Gnome Terminal set to stay open when the command exits. Yeah, I should add the steps.

Comment: Upvote because the question is very well documented, but I would take a different approach, i.e. start the application in a terminal that is already open. It would likely take a feature request to have the developpers make this message not covering existing terminal output or providing an option to disable the message. Alternatively, find another terminal emulator that performs more like you would wish.